# error C3867 when calling class function with CreateThread

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, createthread

I try to pass a class function to CreateThread called from main function, I got error :

> error C3867: 'Display::fill_matrix': function call missing argument list; use '&Display::fill_matrix' to create a pointer to member

---

```
class Display
{
public:
    Display();
    DWORD WINAPI fill_matrix();
};
```

---

```
Display display;
main() {
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, display.fill_matrix, NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fill_matrix()` is a non-static member function. Therefore its first argument is a pointer to a `Display` class instance. That is what the compiler complains about. The normal way to solve this is make a static member function and pass that to `CreateThread`. Here is what it would like :

```
class Display
{
public:
    Display();

    static DWORD WINAPI fill_matrix_static(void* obj_ptr) {
        Display* display_ptr = (Display*) obj_ptr;
        return display_ptr->fill_matrix();
    }

    DWORD WINAPI fill_matrix();
};
```

and then call it like this :

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, fill_matrix_static, (void*) &display, 0, 0);
```